# using Binance Api for wallet address verification

Tags: php, laravel, binance, binance-api-client, binance-smart-chain

I want to verify the user's wallet address using Binance API.
like if the user enters the Binance USDT wallet address while signup I just want to check if he entered the correct Binance wallet address or PAY ID.
please guide us if there is any solution using Binance's official API or some tool to check

I checked every API in Binance but did not find anything related to my query

Answer (score 1):

For the privacy matters, Binance don't let others know which wallet is for whom, so the simple answer is : You can't !

No need to say that you can check if wallet is correct or have balance, but you can't check who or on which site wallet has been created. You should simply ask your users to use Binance wallet.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion.
Please let me know if there is any API in which I send the user a small amount like 0.000001 USDT using pay ID after registration of a user

Comment: Sure, in which blockchain you need to do this ? Consider that most of the blockchains charge fee on token transfer and send lots of small amount like 0.000001 USDT may not be a good call.

Comment: Sir 0.000001 USDt its just an example. I want to send using Binance api using pay id

Comment: If you just simply send USDT to another account in Binance using API, it's possible and you can use other's user ID or email.